# Woocommerce rating once per user

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, rating-system

I am using the ratings system that comes standard with woocommerce but if a user is logged into their account they can add multiple ratings/reviews for the same item over and over again. How can you restrict the user from doing that? If the user wants to re-rate something they already rated then it should edit their existing rating, NOT create a new(duplicate) review/rating

Comment: No one has any suggestions?